# Trying to find an error i made without the document availible

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In trying to find the summation of 1-20 with n^2/Pi^2 I receive a summation of the total being 21.2774 as opposed to the correct answer of 290.7918. The first line of my table showed a correct answer to the formula being 0.1013. I do not have access to the old document to see where my mistakes where made so I am trying top work backwards at this point but have not been successful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This should work for you: `=SUMPRODUCT(ROW($1:$20)^2/PI()^2)`

Comment: That still gives the correct value of 290.7918 im trying to work backwards and find the mistake in my previous formula that resulted in 21.2774

Comment: Also, the only way to get an answer of 21.2774 is if the 1-20 is not being squared in the numerator.  It means the formula looked liked n/Pi^2 instead of n^2/Pi^2

Comment: Which would make sense why the first one (1) calculated correctly, because 1^2 = 1 so it didn't matter

Comment: thank you for some reason I didn't think of un squaring the first value the help is much appreciated.